# How can implement react-google-maps DirectionsRenderer in my project

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I am building a simple project that if a user clicks a button it should show directions from the user's location to the destination which I mark. Here is my code.
I have just implemented some parts but I did not understand how to implement DirectionsRenderer and could not learn from articles, docs. Now I have no idea what to do. Can anyone explain me in a easier way? Thank you!

```
  GoogleMap,
  withGoogleMap,
  withScriptjs,
  DirectionsRenderer,
} from 'react-google-maps';

import Marker from 'react-google-maps/lib/components/Marker';
function Map() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={10}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 51.507351, lng: -0.127758 }}
      >
        <Marker position={{ lat: 51.4666, lng: -0.213 }} />
      </GoogleMap>
    </div>
  );
}
const DirectionsService = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();
DirectionsService.route({
  origin: new window.google.maps.LatLng(41.85073, -87.65126),
  destination: new window.google.maps.LatLng(41.85258, -87.65141),
  travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
});
const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));

function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100vw', height: '100vh' }}>
      <WrappedMap
        googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_MAP_KEY}`}
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I made to achieve your use-case:

1. Use the browser's `HTML5 Geolocation feature` to get the user's current position inside the `componentDidMount`.
2. Then use state variables to hold the value of the current location. You also put the value of the user current location state to `center` parameter of your `GoogleMap` object so that the map will show the area of the map where the user is.  This will be used as the `origion` of your Directions service.
   3.Also use another state to hold the user current location. This is to be used as state to put a marker in the user current location.
3. Call a function inside the `onClick` parameter of your `GoogleMap` object. Then use another state variable that will hold the value of the clicked coordinates. This will be used as the `destination` of the Directions Service.
4. Put a button on top of your map div and call a function inside its `OnClick` parameter.The function will call the `GoogleMaps directionsService` and will calculate a route between your origin and destination. If there's a route, you use another state variable to hold the result of the Directions service.
5. Use the `DirectionsRenderer` object inside the GoogleMap object to display the polyline of the route.

Here's the [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/directions-on-btn-click-uzxt6c?file=Map.js) (*Note: Make sure to put your API key in the index.js for the sample to work*) and the code snippet below:

```
/*global google*/
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import {
  withGoogleMap,
  Marker,
  GoogleMap,
  DirectionsRenderer
} from 'react-google-maps';
class Map extends Component {
  state = {
    directions: null,
    markerPos: null,
    centerMarker: null,
    currentLocation: null
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    navigator?.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      ({ coords: { latitude: lat, longitude: lng } }) => {
        const pos = { lat, lng };
        this.setState({ currentLocation: pos, centerMarker: pos });
      }
    );
  };

  onMapClick = e => {
    this.setState({ markerPos: e.latLng });
  };

  getDirections = () => {
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    const origin = this.state.currentLocation;
    const destination = this.state.markerPos;

    if (origin !== null && destination !== null) {
      directionsService.route(
        {
          origin: origin,
          destination: destination,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        },
        (result, status) => {
          if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            this.setState({
              directions: result
            });
          } else {
            console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      console.log('Please mark your destination in the map first!');
    }
  };

  render() {
    const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 }}
        defaultZoom={13}
        center={this.state.currentLocation}
        onClick={this.onMapClick}
      >
        {this.state.centerMarker !== null && (
          <Marker position={this.state.centerMarker} label={'userloc'} />
        )}
        {this.state.markerPos !== null && (
          <Marker position={this.state.markerPos} />
        )}
        {this.state.directions !== null && (
          <DirectionsRenderer
            directions={this.state.directions}
            defaultOptions={{
              suppressMarkers: true
            }}
          />
        )}
      </GoogleMap>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.getDirections}>Get Direction</Button>
        <GoogleMapExample
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: '500px' }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```